# How can I separate numbering and header styles in Microsoft Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

**Updated to reflect that I do want to have a set of headers without numbering and another set with numbering.**

In a document I created four new heading styles (NumHeading 1 - 4) each based on Heading 1 through Heading 4. In my document I created four lines each assigned to my new heading styles.

For each line I modified it by making it a list item. This updated the NumHeading styles with numbering such that I have each line looking like this:

```
1.0       NumHeading 1 (I added a .0 to the the formatting for number)
1.1       NumHeading 2
1.2       NumHeading 2 second line
1.1.1     NumHeading 3
1.1.1.1   NumHeading 4
```

This is exactly what I want.

If assign one of NumHeadings to a fresh Normal line I get the effects that I wanted.

But I found that if I use one of the standard headings it has also taken on the properties of the numbered list including the hanging indent.

I wanted to add my custom NumHeading styles to my normal template, but if it overrides the standard headings it seems to be moot point. With the next best thing to create a separate template for this type of document.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, but why did you apply the list style manually instead of including it as part of the heading style?

Comment: The only way I know how to add the list style is to modify an item associated with a header style. If I go directly to numbering in the style editor, List styles are not shown.  I tired creating a List Style directly, but after creating it I could not get it to show in the Style list to select it.  It did show up when I went to manage styles, but the placement was listed as last and the buttons that control the placement in the style list were disabled.

Comment: "I wanted to add these styles to my normal template, but if it overrides the standard header it seems to be moot point" - do you want Heading 1-4 to include the list numbers in every document you create from now on based on the normal template - or - do you want to keep the default Heading 1-4 styles, and create your own MyHeading 1-4 with the list numbering?

Comment: I wanted to have the originals without numbering and my new numbered list headers. So I could use either from the Normal template.

Answer (score 0):

(Understood that the poster has long since moved on. This is for others searching for something similar.)

I recommend basing the NumHeadings on the Normal style and formatting the paragraph styles of each to the appropriate outline level (Paragraph, Indents and Spacing tab, Outline Level dropdown). To best control numbering, create a list numbering style linked to the NumHeadings.

[image: List Numbering]

The process is described on the Shauna Kelly Word website: [Link to webpage describing numbered list styles](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html?p=1768)